# upgrade to highstock 1.3.1 breaks resize code

Tags: highcharts

How to resize with the latest code.  The examples now use

```
chart = $('#theChart').highcharts({
```

Instead of newing a HighStockChart

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
```

I am not sure if that new way assigning chart variable is working though AND chart.setSize is definitely no longer working.  I use to have this resize code...

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var height = getHeight();
    console.log('fit new div container size, width='+$("#theChart").width()+' height='+height+' windowH='+$(window).height());
    chart.setSize($("#theChart").width(), height, false);
});
```

which breaks on calling setSize.  The width of my chart automatically changes but the height no longer changes anymore.  I tried setting the height on the div on resize but that did not work at all.  How to dynamically change the chart size to fit in the window but have a min-height as well if collapsed to far.

(My zoom panel also completely broke as well...is there a good example for that as I now need to add that back).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

You can still call `chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options)` to create charts.

However now `$("#container").highcharts(options);` returns jQuery object, not Highcharts chart. To get chart from created id use: `$("#container").highcharts();` (empty highcharts())

Comment: switching back to new Highcharts.StockChart(options) screwed things up.  I will try the second option and see how that works.

Comment: chart = $("#container").highcharts(); does not work since chart.setSize() fails with no such method

Comment: Most probably you forget in new Highcharts.StockChart() add renderTo option. Second option - see Sebastian's example - works perfectly. Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please.

Answer (score 1):

At the newest version you can still use first construction: 
http://jsfiddle.net/L6hpm/

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart:{
            renderTo:'container'
        },
```

I second solution you can use:

http://jsfiddle.net/NbHj9/

```
 var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

        chart.setSize(100,100);
```

Comment: there is something screwy with new Highcharts.StockChart...swithing out for ${'#container').highcharts() makes it work but that does not return the chart that has a setSize method.. http://jsfiddle.net/C4eYK/

Comment: chart = $("#container").highcharts(); does not work since chart.setSize() fails with no such method

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this:

```
var chartOptions = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: '[id of div]',
    },
    xAxis:{

    },
     ...
    series:{

    },
};

var chartName = new Highcharts.chart({chartsOptions});
```

This should definitely work for you....just use chartName.setOptions() to set the size